# If by calculating a velocity I end up with $v = \sqrt{1}$

Tags: kinematics, velocity

Do I then take the $-1$ as the answer or the $+1$? I'm asking because in my situation the velocity is going in the opposite direction than what the positive direction was deemed to be. Do I just take the $-1$, or do I take the $+1$ and then assign a direction sign ($-1$) to it. And why?

edit:
The object goes from A to B in the positive right direction, hits a wall at B with velocity $1.4m/s$ , goes back from B to A with initial velocity $-1m/s$.

Comment: Not enough context is given to effectively answer.

Comment: The object goes from A to B in the positive right direction, hits a wall at B with velocity 1.4m/s , goes back from B to A with initial velocity -1m/s.

Comment: What is the Q ? You have not specified for what you are writing -1 and +1 as ??

Comment: @sweetiesakura - please [edit] the question with appropriate context (what is the setup, what is known, what is calculated, etc). The comments isn't the place to add details for the question.

Comment: i've already edited it for you

Answer (score 2):

I presume this result comes from solving a quadratic equation. In most cases, you will obtain two different answers, both of which are valid mathematically (solves the equation you wrote down initially). The rest is physics: pick out the one that makes sense in the context of the problem. Without more information I'm afraid I cannot do better than this.

As a simple example, if you obtain a time of $t=2 s$ and $t=-4s$ for a ball to hit the ground after being thrown with some initial conditions including the fact that the ball was thrown at $t=0$, you should pick the positive answer.

Comment: well in my question an object goes from A to B , hits a wall at B and moves back from B to A. And the direction that i took as positive is to the right ( A --> B). when it hits B i calculate the velocity at which it hits B with is ( 1.4 m/s) and at which it leaves B with is (√1 m /s)

Comment: If you've determined the object to be moving opposite of how it originally was, then a negative sign is appropriate. Using conservation of momentum is an easy way to figure this out. Note that it is possible for objects to be moving in the same direction after a collision (think train hitting a car).

Comment: yes, but that's not what my question asked. i asked if i should directly take the -ve sqroot or if i should take the +ve sqroot then assign the -ve sign to it because of the direction. i know it sounds more like a math question than a physics question at this stage...

Comment: Ah ok, my apologies, I misunderstood. You should (see edit) take the positive root, and determine the sign based on the physics (your latter option).

Edit: This will not always be true because for more general cases, the roots are asymmetrical (they might both be positive, or both be negative). It's also possible that both answers are valid physically.

Answer (score 1):

From a mathematical point of view, $\sqrt 1$ is shorthand for the solutions to the equation $x^2=1$, which is the set $\{-1,1\}$. Whether you then choose $-1$ or $1$ from this set depend on the physical constraints within the problem.

This may appear to be overly precise, but you need to bear in mind that the solutions to a quadratic equation are not necessarily symmetric about $0$. If the quadratic equation were $x^2-3x+2$ then the solutions set is $\{1,2\}$ which no longer fits the pattern $\{-a,a\}$.